# How to get type of Nullable data type?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have field's data type defined in database. I want to convert field's value to its specific data type.
The code below works for `System.Int32`

```
 var fieldValue = "1234";
 var fieldDataType = "System.Int32";
 var type = Type.GetType(fieldDataType);
 TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
 var result = typeConverter.ConvertFromString(fieldValue);
```

However, It does not work when dataType is  `System.Nullable<System.Int32>`

What is the valid value for Nullable Integer DataType? (I am going to use the same for other datatypes)

**EDIT 1 ( More details)**
In database i have fields defined along with their data types. I am rendering `TextBox` dynamically on UI for each field. When user submits the `form`, I am using custom model binding in `ASP.NET Core` to bind these fields to JObject.
Something like below

```
var model = new MyModel()
   {
     CustomFields = new JObject()
   };

foreach(var key in form.Keys)
{
    var val = form[key];

    var fields = GetFieldsFromDB();
    var field = fileds.Where(x=>x.FieldName == key).Single();
    

     TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Type.GetType(field.DataType);
       var result = typeConverter.ConvertFromString(fieldValue);

     model.CustomFields.Add(key,result);
    
  
}
```

I am trying to avoid `switch` statement or `if else` for each available .Net DataTypes

Comment: You can try using "System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32]]".But I would recommend to store bit filed for nullable value types.

Comment: @GuruStron  `But I would recommend to store bit filed for nullable value types` can please explain

Comment: There's not enough information here to provide a good answer (but you'll get bad ones, such as below). It's important for you to explain how you're going to use this information. Because on the face of it, you should be storing the underlying data type, and so `"System.Int32"` is fine. You just need to inspect the nullable type's generic type parameter type to get that. On the other hand, if you have a specific need to deserialize _as_ a nullable type, that might be different. Please improve the question.

Comment: @LP13 I assume your type string is coming somewhere outside(database for example), maybe wrong here (but otherwise I don't see need to handle strings here), so I would recommend introducing another column to indicate that type is nullable value type instead of relaying on C# internal constructed generic type name representation.

Comment: @GuruStron got it. Yes there are defined in JSON. I can certainly add a bool property indicating if this field is Nullable. However i was looking for a way to avoid using switch statement for each .NET DataTypes

Comment: Not following why you will need a switch here. But without whole code it's hard to argue. Actually I strongly doubt that this representation will change, so you can go with it, but still better safe than sorry) Also move `var fields = GetFieldsFromDB();` out of `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the internal type name:

```
var fieldDataType = "System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]";
```

This is also what's computed by:

```
var fieldDataType = "" + typeof(Nullable<int>);
```

Comment: What is wrong with `typeof(Nullable<int>).ToString()` ?

Comment: Thanks, I had a brain-fart! Your suggestion is a good idea.